# how to resolve Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'corner' in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, liferay-theme, liferay-velocity

I am using `jquery round corner plugin` in lifray theme in order to add round corner functionality in all kind of browsers, including IE6 to IE8. i have included the jquery round corner plugin in portla_normal.vm like this :-

```
<head>
    <title>$the_title - $company_name</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/html/js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>                    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="$javascript_folder/jquery_roundcorner.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="$javascript_folder/jquery.corner.js"></script>

        $theme.include($top_head_include)

 </head>
```

This is my `jquery_roundcorner.js` file, when i see on console of the browser  getting the error in this file like below.

```
$(document).ready(function()    {
    $('#navigation li').corner("round 6px");
    $('#navigation a').corner("round 6px");
});
```

I am geting following error on browser console:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'corner'.`

Can any one help me how to resolve this?

Comment: why `$` on the starting of src link

Comment: First, make sure all the libraries are loaded. Second, does `corner.js` need to come before `roundercorner.js`?

Comment: Ensure that the js files are being loaded properly. Also, can you share the final generated markup?

Comment: I think @PranavRam is right. These '$' will corrupt the path and the scripts will not load. This will mean .corner will not be a function and this error will happen. Try removing the `$`. If that fixed it have PranavRam put this in an answer and give it the check mark. Don't let someone steal his answer though.

Comment: In other words `src="$javascript_folder/jquery_roundcorner.js"` should be `src="javascript_folder/jquery_roundcorner.js"` and `src="$javascript_folder/jquery.corner.js"` should be `src="javascript_folder/jquery.corner.js"`. Thanks @PranavRam

Comment: This might be PHP, folks.

Comment: $ is the symbol to access the variable in velocity file. the above jquery plugins i included in velocity file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my jquery_roundcorner.js i have  replaced the above code with the following code. Actually in  velocity file also $ is used, there may be conflicts. so lastly i tried this, its working now.

```
var jq=$.noConflict();
jq(document).ready(function(){
    alert('hello alert1 ');
    jq('#navigation li').corner("round 6px");
    jq('#navigation a').corner("round 6px");
    alert('hello alert3 ');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<head>
   <title>$the_title - $company_name</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/html/js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="$javascript_folder/jquery.corner.js"></script>             
   <script type="text/javascript" src="$javascript_folder/jquery_roundcorner.js"></script>
   $theme.include($top_head_include)
</head>
```

alter the load javascript order!

you have to make sure the jquery plugin is first loaded!